# What are the consequences of a nested mapping?

Tags: solidity, mapping

I'm wondering what the consequences of using a nested mapping are.  If I have a mapping that is 4 levels deep, for example:

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256))) validTokens;
```

Are there significant performance costs associated with a mapping that deep, which I could avoid by using an array of structs and iterating through them?